# How can I use embed-python module in windows and ubuntu OS

Tags: python, embed

Maybe It looks weird, I want to develop application which runs on windows and linux. So I downloaded embed-python-3.6.7 and then try to understand how to install  packages from pip. But every modules are zipped into Python.zip

C:\Users.....\Downloads\python-3.6.7-embed-win32>python -c "import os; print(os)"

How do I install the modules?

Answer (score 1):

Python IS cross platform

I'm not familiar with this `embed-python` module, but if you want to create desktop application for windows and Linux, you can write you code normally, then use `PyInstaller` to package it as an executable

Please check out [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-pyinstaller) .